# How to test for group differences in age in a mixed effects model?

Tags: mixed-model

I'm retrospectively analyzing how performance changes with age in two diagnostic groups. The data is a bit all over the place - some participants have performance measured multiple times per visit, and some participants came in for multiple visits. Before analyzing the performance data, I want to make sure that the two groups do not differ in age. My initial plan was to use mixed-effects models for everything (including differences in age):

```
Age ~ Group + (1 | Subject)
```

Is this correct? I'm not having very much luck online, and I think I'm overthinking things ...

Comment: Is age time-varying? The model you've specified here assumes so. Even if age is time-varying, is that important to your question? Can you just look at age differences at baseline, in which case, a `glm` will be all you need.

Comment: @ErikRuzek yes, age is time-varying. For example, Participant #1 may have came in at 2 years and 4 years, Participant #2 only at 7 years, and Participant #3 came in at 8 and 8.5 years. I'm going to be analyzing the performance data, looking for changes with age, group, and group-by-age, but I first want to make sure that there are no group differences in age to begin with.

Comment: Technically the model you asked about could be run, but I find it conceptually odd. Specifically, the random intercept, which accounts for correlations in age for subjects is hard to understand. Why would you want to account for such correlations? At any rate, I'd suggest pairing down your data to one observation for each subject per visit (getting rid of the multiple observations per visit for some subjects). Then you can run this model.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are overcomplicating ... For each person in the study, you could just focus on their age at entry. Then you have one observation per person, and the problem is reduced to a two-sample test problem!